# Google Script Run ClockTrigger Multiple Scripts

Tags: email, google-apps-script, triggers

The situation I have is this:

> - a google form signup where people can sign up for notifications
> - a series of scripts that I would like to run nightly that looks through the form responses and emails people appropriately, Emailer()
> - an unsubscribe script that ideally runs frequently (every hour or so would be enough) as well as right before the notifications email is
>     sent. This looks through the inbox for emails and removes the
>     appropriate entries from the form responses, Unsubscriber()

I am having trouble coming up with a way to coordinate the way these two scripts will run. What I would like to happen is to have Unsubscriber() run every hour or so throughout the day. At midnight or some late night hour, I would like to run Emailer() once and have the Unsubscriber() function not be running at this time. Once Emailer() completes, I would like the Unsubscriber() function to resume running at its regular interval. I feel like this should be possible using a ClockTrigger, but I can't envision how to make it happen.

I am also wondering, if the Unsubscriber() function is scheduled to run every hour with a ClockTrigger, but takes longer than an hour on a certain instance, will the ClockTrigger start a second instance of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) is the documentation on how to create manually a time trigger, you can set the function to run every hour.

This trigger could be related to a main function in which you could evaluate the current time, if its in the range of midnight (e.g. 12am < current time > 1am) call the function Emailer(), for every other time of the day call Unsuscriber().

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo.. I had considered that. My only concern is if the Emailer() script completes before an hour elapses won't it be run again?

Comment: wait, nevermind. It will only be called once an hour. Then i guess my question is what if Emailer() takes longer than an hour? Will Unsubscriber() run at 1am and then be messing with the spreadsheet at the same time?

Comment: I suppose a not so elegant solution would be to have the clock trigger call for a longer waiting period, such as 4-6 hours. I know that for a relatively small number of form responses (<1000 probably) this would be way more than enough. I can monitor how long the script takes to complete and adjust the interval accordingly.

Comment: Your scrip won't run more than an hour, scripts can run only for 6 mins, after this time the server will stop the script and an exception will be thrown. here is the information on script quotas: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Thanks again, I hadn't noticed that quota limit. i suppose 6 minutes is quite a long time in computer ticks